# IIS7 - Using an ip address and port number will not display a web site home page but using localhost will

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, localhost, default

Using ASP.Net I did a web site and can load it up in a browser window when pressing the F5 key in VS2010.

On the browser window I noticed VS2010 used an address like this to load the web site home page:

```
localhost:12345/
```

If I try to use the ip address for my computer found by using ipconfig to load up the home page,

```
1.2.3.4:12345
```

I get an error stating:

```
Could not connect to 1.2.3.4:12345
```

If I use:

```
1.2.3.4
```

I get the IIS7 default page.

The actual address and port numbers I used in this example are different than those I really used.

Can you tell me why localhost works but 1.2.3.4 does not work?

Can you tell me if I need to do something extra with IIS7 since I never did this before?

Comment: Why do you need this? Did you publish your site to IIS?

Comment: Because that web server is not meant to be a public webserver, and only responds to requests on localhost/127.0.0.1 by default.

Comment: I'm using IIS to view the web site I'm developing locally on my development computer so I wanted to try and log on to the web site as if I was a user using the internet.

Comment: Can you are using IIS and not Cassini?

Comment: Check your IIS bindings then for the website. You'll need the correct IP and hostname bindings.

Comment: Lloyd, can you tell me how to work with binding since this is the first time trying this?

Comment: Maybe this question should be re-opened because other people like it. I earned a "Popular Question" badge for it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to remeber.  Your computer two types of IP address.  The first is a private IP address and the second is a public IP adress.  IPConfig will show you your local, private address.  Your private address will not be accessible from anywhere outside your LAN.

If you would like to change your websites URL locally from localhost, you need to change your IDE's development settings.

This [site](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/21/how-to-run-a-root-site-with-the-vs-vwd-2005-local-web-server.aspx) has a great tutorial on how to do that.

Comment: That tutorial looks great. If I set things up based on the tutorial, will I be able to use another computer that's not on our LAN to access the web site that's on IIS ?

Comment: If your intent is to have the site available for testing purposes, you would need to set your public IP on the IDE's configuration page.  In order to do this you need a static IP address (your ISP can tell you if you have one).  If you have a static IP, got to the site http://whatismyipaddress.com and you will see your IP displayed.  If your intent is to use this in production, I would recommend looking into a hosted platform solution such as GoDaddy, Heroku, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the address Visual Studio gives you is a temporal address that corresponds to their development server (Webdev.Webhost or Cassini), this server doesn't allow you to connect outside your computer, that's why localhost:1234 opens your page, but 5.6.7.8:1234 doesn't.

Second, also you seem to have IIS configured, but what you need to do is deploy your site to IIS, here are Microsoft information about deploying your site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b(v=vs.100).aspx, once deployed, you may create an Application on IIS or a Virtual Directory, for more information you can take a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042(v=ws.10).aspx.

Once you have deployed and configured your application or virtual directory, you can access your site like this: localhost/MyVirtualDirectory (assuming you set a virtual directory).